# How can I split the first element of a nested list element?

Tags: python, list, split, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Let's imagine we have:

```
test = [['word.II', 123, 234],
    ['word.IV', 321, 123],
    ['word.XX', 345, 345],
    ['word.XIV', 345, 432]
   ]
```

How can I split the first element in the test so that the result would be:

```
test = [['word', 'II', 123, 234],
    ['word', 'IV', 321, 123],
    ['word', 'XX', 345, 345],
    ['word', 'XIV', 345, 432]
   ]
```

Among other things I've tried:

```
test = [[row[0].split('.'), row[1], row[2]] for row in test],
```

but that results in:

```
[['word', 'II'], 123, 234]
[['word', 'IV'], 321, 123]
[['word', 'XX'], 345, 345]
[['word', 'XIV'], 345, 432]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach could be to use `split` to split the first element (as you did!) and then concatenate it to the rest of the list using the `+` operator:

```py
result = [row[0].split('.') + row[1::] for row in test]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!
I also tried: 

`test  = [row[0].split('.') + row[1] + row[2] for row in test]`

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: @user14513812, because `row[0].split('.') ` is list while `row[1]` and `row[2]` are integers. And you can't concatenate them. However, you could have used `test  = [row[0].split('.') + [row[1]] + [row[2]] for row in test]`

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to do that:

```
new_test = [row[0].split('.')+ row[1:] for row in test]
```

+ operator concatenates lists, for example:

```
>>>[2,3,4] + [1,5]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
list(map(lambda x:x[0].split('.')+x[1:],test))
```

Answer (score 3):

using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and list addition:

```
spam = [['word.II', 123, 234],
    ['word.IV', 321, 123],
    ['word.XX', 345, 345],
    ['word.XIV', 345, 432]]


eggs = [first.split('.') + rest for first, *rest in spam]
print(eggs)
```

output:

```
[['word', 'II', 123, 234], ['word', 'IV', 321, 123],
 ['word', 'XX', 345, 345], ['word', 'XIV', 345, 432]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works as well:

```
test = [[row[0].split('.')[0], row[0].split('.')[1], row[1], row[2]] for row in test]
```

Comment: Thank you! This lets me see it from another perspective, too!